# I am building an app using android studios and the app tutorial. Having problems identifying a file

Tags: java, android

I am instructed to input a method in MyActivity.java file, however I do not see this file but I do have a file named MainActivity.java.  Would these files be considered the same.

Here is an image of the instructions and the file I have in my IDE.

[image]

Comment: MainActivity appears to be the activity that you've created so use that. You should check that the manifest (AndroidManifest.xml) says to launch .Mainactivity. e.g. it will have something along the lines of `<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>` within it.

Comment: It did, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The path of the file they are referring to is simply an example and is different for every application. It goes in your `MainActivity.java`